# SQL return all the results from left table

Tags: sql

Trying to run a query that will give me all items from the left table and their corresponding specific detail from the right table. The problem I am running into is that if the corresponding data from the right table does not exist for a specific row, that whole row is not returned. I have tried "Left Join" but it has the same result.

Example:

```
Table 1:        Table 2: 
Car1            BMW
Car2            Audi
Car3
```

I want a list of all cars and what the brand is. If there is no brand associated with the car right now, that specific car would not show up when I run the query. So in this case, Car3 is not showing up at all. If I only run a query to show me the first table, then Car3 shows up fine. Thanks for any help!

It seems that the issue is with the "where" as I have a condition that is limiting the results, and it does not have to do with the type of Join.

Comment: How are these tables related?

Comment: A left join should give you what you are looking for.  Can you post your query?

Comment: What is your current query?

Comment: LEFT JOIN is the solution here, you're making another error

Comment: why would someone forget to write their query in this kind of scenario. It goes beyond my understanding.

Comment: Please post the columns of your tables and also what is the query you are using now, since there is no reason for the `LEFT JOIN` to "not work"

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT va.[Serial Number] AS Expr2, va.Barcode, va.Model AS Expr4, va.Manufacturer AS Expr5, dbo.Item.Name FROM         dbo.Item LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ResourceAssociation AS ResourceAssociation_1 ON ResourceAssociation_1.ChildResourceGuid = dbo.Item.Guid LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vAsset AS va ON ResourceAssociation_1.ParentResourceGuid

Comment: This is not the full query. Some lines are missing at the end.

Comment: @richard chaaya Your query is cut off as comment field is too short (comments are NOT used for this, edit your original post!). Also, please provide a working SQL fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some data so we can easily see what you want, it is not very clear now.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo query like this will help

```
select car.*,Brand.* from car LEFT JOIN Brand
on Car.brand_ID = Brand.brand_ID
```